Fixing a local markdown image reference in AstroJS?
I have this folder structure in my astroJS project, where I seperate each blog content by an YYYYMMDD name prefix
pages
  blogs
    20220505
      index.md
      img/pikachu.png
    20230401
      index.md
      img/charizard.png

I am running into an issue in one of these index.md files, where I am trying to do a local image reference inside the markdown file. e.g. ![](./img/charizard.png)
Example in one of the index.md files above
---
layout: ../../../layouts/Blog.astro
title: 'Greatest pokemon of all time'
subtitle: 'Charizard'
poster: '/images/roadmap.jpg'
---

Charizard is great

![](./img/charizard.png)

When I run npm run dev, this gives me an error on missing sharp below

How do I go about resolving this?

I encountered the same issue today and resolved it by checking the GitHub issues for AstroJS. One particular comment was helpful.
Here’s what worked:

Delete the package-lock.json file and node-modules.
Manually downgrade the Sharp library by modifying the package.json to use: sharp": "0.32.4.

You can find the discussion at this link: GitHub Discussion.
